# DOM elements not loading on-time for jQuery function (jQuery slider evolution)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I know that before using jQuery on dom elements it is best practice to encompass your code within `$(document).ready`.

The last question I asked on here dealt with the fact that I was trying to size a custom jQuery widget by selecting an image size and setting the widget to that size. The problem was that the image would not load on time for the jQuery code to select it and use it. I ended up fixing that problem with `$('#image1').load`.

The new problem I am facing comes from the fact that this jQuery widget does not resize with the window as the images themselves do. I am using this code to do the re-adjustment.

```
$(window).resize(function () {
        var imageWidth = $(window).width()

        $(".slider").width(imageWidth);

        $("#image1").width(imageWidth);

        $("#image2").width(imageWidth);
    });
```

The code works; however, every once in a while on the initial load of the page the images do not load on time and I can only see the widget itself. I am able to see the navigation controls which indicate there there are indeed two photos except that the photos are not displayed and the widget seems to look like it is in a collapsed state.

Here is the full code for the page.

```
<section class="featured">
    <div class="slider" style="width: 100%">
        <div class="slider-image">
            <img id="image1" src="~/Content/images/NSXBanner.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="slider-image">
            <img id="image2" src="~/Content/images/civicBanner.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    /*This resizes the slider widget and animations along with the window size changed event*/
    $(window).resize(function () {
        var imageWidth = $(window).width()

        $(".slider").width(imageWidth);

        $("#image1").width(imageWidth);

        $("#image2").width(imageWidth);
    });

    $('#image1').load(function () {
        var imageWidth = $('#slider').width()
        var imageHeight = $('#image1').height()

        $(".slider").slideshow({
            width: imageWidth,
            height: imageHeight,
            transition: 'bar'
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you able to set the image width and height up front ? `<img id="image1" width="300" height="300" src="~/Content/images/NSXBanner.jpg" />` - as the browser will then dedicate that space for it before it has downloaded/rendered.

Comment: Other than that try it by moving your `$(window).resize(..` function inside your  `$('#image1').load(.. ` function

Comment: I currently have my images using width:100%; height:auto;. I will try both ways but I'm not sure if setting a static dimension would be good because my image might look really huge on smaller screens.

Comment: if you are width:100%, height: auto, then agree, not point setting the inline dimensions

Comment: Okay, moving the re-size code to the image.load section seemed to do the trick. I thought doing this might keep the re size code from running when the browser is re sized since it was in the Load method of an element but not so.

Comment: Makes sense, you do not want to start the resize listener until you know you can access the properties of the image.